# gnuplot: how to use thin but large fonts?

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I have a plot with many straight lines and instead of adding a key describing every single straight line, I plan to summarize their description using a curly brace. So for I have reached here:

[image]

As we can see, the curly brace is too thick compared to rest of the elements in the plot and I want something thinner there. How do I go about doing this?

Note: I am using pdfcairo terminal.

Comment: Am using pdfcairo terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a latex-based terminal you can resize the braces symbol using [a zero-width rule with the desired height](http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/Curly-braces-drawing-td12407.html):

```
set label 1 '$\left.\rule{0cm}{1cm}\right\}$'  at 10,9
plot [0:10] x, 0.9*x, 0.8*x
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Am using pdfcairo terminal.